# How to properly setup controller injection with many related entities

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, controller, service-layer

I am wondering if what I am doing here is appropriate. I have an model in my database called **Request**. A Request has a lot of relationships with other tables (such as categories, notes, etc.)

So naturally I created CRUD services to wrap logic for each of those such as:

- IRequestService
- IRequestNoteService
- IRequestKPIService

Now, I have a controller called **RequestController**. That naturally needs to get all the Requests along with the related **properties/entities**. This in turn causes my RequestController to have a substantial number of interfaces injected:

```
public RequestController(
    IMapper mapper,
    IRequestService requestService,
    IRequestorService requestorService,
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
    IWebHostEnvironment environment,
    IRequestCategoryService requestCategoryService,
    IRequestNoteService requestNoteService,
    ICommitteeNoteService committeeNoteService)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _requestService = requestService;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _requestorService = requestorService;
        _environment = environment;
        _requestCategoryService = requestCategoryService;
        _requestNoteService = requestNoteService;
        _committeeNoteService = committeeNoteService;
        //etc.
    }
```

**With functions such as:**

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> GetRequestKPIs() { }
 public async Task<JsonResult> GetRequests() { }
 public async Task<JsonResult> GetNotesForRequest(int RequestIdForNote) { }
 public async Task<JsonResult> UpdateNoteForRequest() { }
 public async Task<JsonResult> DeleteATGRequest(int Id) { }
```

etc....

**My Question:**

So my gripe at the end of the day is I inject a CRUD interface for a related model, but im only using the GET portions of it in this particular controller.

Would it be better for me to call separate controllers for related data which in turn uses those specific interfaces, like **RequestNoteController**, **RequestorController**, etc. which would contain functions like **UpdateRequestNote()**? Or do I need to create a specific class that implements the interfaces relevant to what I want in the RequestController.

Overall I am trying to understand what is the right way to organize controllers / service layer functions with a model that has **LOTS OF RELATED ENTITIES**. I have been having a hard time finding examples / explanations for this on google. If anyone could give me what the typical convention is for this or some articles that could be of help that would be a huge help for me understanding on others separate these things out.

Comment: I think you have the intention of having all the data come back to a specific primary key. Maybe you can go one level further and abstract your datamodel to return back with the data that you would have otherwise returned in the other methods.

Comment: Unforunately the way the front end framework is setup these functions are required in this way. These are being used to read data for drop down lists and more.

Comment: It would be good to look into the concept of the [Interface Segregation Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle). It might provide some guidance.